# Modus im Relativsatz beim Konjunktiv II im Hauptsatz

Tags: subjunctive, relative-clause

Betrachten wir den folgenden Satz.

> Zwar ließe sich ein präziserer Preis der Buttermilch je nach Standort festlegen, der allen Anforderungen genügt/genügte; wir verzichten jedoch auf solche Standortabweichungen, um unsere Berechnung nicht zu verkomplizieren.

Welchen Modus nutzen wir im Relativsatz? Indikativ (genüge) oder Konjunktiv II (genügte)?  Bitte eine sinnvolle Begründung mitangeben.

Answer (score 2):

Grammatisch ist beides möglich.

> Sie könnte den Ansatz, der allen Anforderungen genügt, verwenden.

Es ist eine Tatsache, dass der Ansatz den Anforderungen genügt. Unklar ist lediglich, ob sie den Ansatz tatsächlich verwendet oder nicht.

> Sie könnte den Ansatz, der allen Anforderungen genügte/genügen würde, verwenden.

Es ist eine Tatsache, dass der Ansatz den Anforderungen genügt. Unklar ist nicht nur, ob sie den Ansatz verwendet oder nicht, sondern auch, ob sie dies erkannt hat.

Answer (score 0):

Die Form im präsenz Subjunktiv (Konjunktiv 1, danke @Björn) lautet *es genüge* [1](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gen%C3%BCgen), so wie der anscheinende Tippfehler in der Frage es schon darstellt. *genügte* wäre demnach schon falsch, da es preterit (also weder Gegenwart, noch Zukunft) ausdrückt.

Man könnte übrigens fragen, ob *genügen* schon eine konjunktive Form ist, wie der Umlaut scheinbar, aber nicht hinreichend andeutet. Immerhin ist die Präsenzform der Erfahrung nach weit üblicher als der Konjunktiv in allen Lagen, die Form mit *würde* ausgenommen.

Update:

Der Satz ist aber schon fragwürdig, da *ließe* im Konjunktiv II nicht unbedingt passend ist. Es spricht nichts dagegen, von einem Ist-Zustand zu sprechen, der durch den Konjunktiv II aber ausgeschlossen wird. Dem Ist-Zustand steht zwar entgegen, dass die Aussage selbst die besprochene Möglichkeit eben nicht wünscht. Die Frage ist nur, ob der Teilsatz mit *genügen* dann auch nicht erwünscht oder gar unmöglich ist. Es ist nicht unerwüscht, dass die benannte Methode genügt, daher ist hier auch keine Übereinstimmung der Modi von *lassen* und *genügen* notwendig. Tatsächlich wird *genügte* in der Regel zuerst als Vergangenheitsform verstanden werden.

Comment: Zum ersten Absatz: Nein, _genüge_ ist Konjunktiv I. Es geht hier aber um den Konjunktiv II, und der lautet nun mal _genügte_. Zum zweiten Absatz: Warum sollte man das fragen? Den Konjunktiv II betreffend, würde die Antwort „nein“ lauten. Und was der Umlaut hiermit zu tun haben soll, erschließt sich mir nicht. Zum dritten Absatz: Die Präsenzform ist üblicher? Als was? Als Präteritum, Perfekt, Plusquamperfekt, Futur? Vermutlich haben Sie sich in der Tabellenspalte geirrt. Präsens gehört da zum Indikativ.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Konjunktiv II, auch Irrealis genannt, passt semantisch kaum. Indirektion aber schon, "ein Preis der allen Anforderungen genügend sei", vgl. [diese Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/51899/35977). Da kann man nur folgern, Ihre anderen unbegründeten Feststellungen seien ebenso unbründet. Stimmt aber nicht ganz, K II drückt auch Wunschvorstellungen aus. Mir fiel auch auf, dass der Umlaut nicht das entscheidende Kriterium zwischen bspw. *möchte* / *mag* (*mögen*) ist; Die Germanische Wurzel von *genügen* aber auch einen Konsonanten-Wandel zeigt. Zudem zeigt *ge-* Partizip.

Comment: So fallen *mag* und *möchte* im Präteritum zusammen, *gemocht*. Leider ist dies das einzige mir bekannte Beispiel für einen verselbstständigten Konjunktiv.

Comment: Zumindest für das Update nehme ich meinen Downvote zurück.