# Warum wird Konjunktiv 1 hier benützt?

Tags: subjunctive

> Es scheint mir nun in der Tat, daß die Beobachtungen über die „schwarze Strahlung“, Photolumineszenz, die Erzeugung von Kathodenstrahlen durch ultraviolettes Licht und andere die Erzeugung bez. Verwandlung des Lichtes betreffende Erscheinungsgruppen besser verständlich erscheinen unter der Annahme, daß die Energie des Lichtes diskontinuierlich im Raume verteilt **sei**.
>   <sub>*Einstein, Albert. "Über einen die Erzeugung und Verwandlung des Lichtes betreffenden heuristischen Gesichtspunkt." Annalen der Physik 322.6 (1905): 132-148.*</sub>

Weil es ein langer, etwas verwirrender Satz für einen Nicht-Muttersprachler ist, auf English:

> It seems to me that the observations associated with blackbody
>   radiation, fluorescence, the production of cathode rays by ultraviolet
>   light, and other related phenomena connected with the emission or
>   transformation of light are more readily understood if one assumes
>   that the energy of light is discontinuously distributed in space.

Warum benützt Einstein "sei" in direkter Rede?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Das tut er, weil er hier von einer Annahme spricht. Hier derselbe Satz mit weniger Ballast:

> Es scheint mir, daß die Beobachtungen verständlich erscheinen **unter der Annahme, daß die Energie diskontinuierlich verteilt sei.**

Er will damit explizit ausdrücken, dass unklar ist, wie die Energie tatsächlich verteilt ist. Wenn man aber annimmt, sie **sei** diskontinuierlich verteilt, würde das als eine mögliche Erklärung für die genannte Beobachtung taugen. Weil aber nicht auszuschließen ist, dass auch andere Ursachen die Beobachtung ebenfalls erklären könnten, ist dieser Zusammenhang noch lange kein Beweis für die diskontinuierliche Verteilung der Energie. Diese Verteilung ist (im Kontext des vorliegenden Textes) nichts weiter als eine unbewiesene Hypothese. (Tatsächlich ist inzwischen längst bewiesen, dass diese Annahme korrekt ist.)

---

Reaktion auf Kommentare:

In einem Kommentar wurde gefragt, warum Einstein nicht den Konjunktiv II gewählt hat. Der Irrealis wird verwendet, um auszudrücken, dass etwas nicht real ist, er wird also verwendet um zu kennzeichnen, dass man von einer Möglichkeit spricht, von der bekannt ist, dass sie unter keinen Umständen eintreten kann. Der Konjunktiv II wird im Deutschen manchmal auch »Irrealis« genannt. Irrealis und Konjunktiv sind in einigen Sprachen (z.B. Türkisch) zwei verschiedene Modi. Im Deutschen wird der Konjunktiv II verwendet, um den Irrealis auszudrücken:

- > Wenn Otto hier **wäre, bekäme** er jetzt eines der neuen Bücher.

  Aber Otto ist nicht hier: Ottos Anwesenheit ist ein irrealer Zustand. Daher ist der Konjunktiv II zu verwenden.

Der gekürzte Satz von Einstein sähe mit Konjunktiv II so aus:

> Es scheint mir, daß die Beobachtungen verständlich erscheinen **unter der Annahme, daß die Energie diskontinuierlich verteilt *wäre.***

Der fett hervorgehobene Teil drückt aus, dass es unmöglich sein kann, dass die Energie diskontinuierlich verteilt ist. Hätte Einstein den Konjunktiv II gewählt, hätte er damit genau das Gegenteil von dem gesagt, worauf er eigentlich hinaus wollte. Die Bedeutung des fett hervorgehobenen Teils (eine diskontinuierleiche Energieverteilung ist unmöglich) kollidiert hier sogar mit dem vorderen Teil des Satzes (man versteht die Beobachtungen).

Da stellt sich dann natürlich auch gleich die Frage, warum Einstein nicht gleich den Indikativ verwendet hat:

> Es scheint mir, daß die Beobachtungen verständlich erscheinen **unter der Annahme, daß die Energie diskontinuierlich verteilt *ist.***

Der Indikativ drückt aber eine *Tatsache* aus. Der Indikativ wäre richtig gewesen, wenn es schon stichfeste Beweise dafür gegeben hätte, dass die Energie tatsächlich diskontinuierlich verteilt ist. Das war aber nicht der Fall. Diese Art der Verteilung stand im Kontext des einsteinschen Aufsatzes nur als vorerst unbewiesene Hypothese zur Diskussion. Der Indikativ wäre also genauso falsch gewesen wie der Konjunktiv II.

Comment: Aber warum nicht benützt er [Konjunktive II][http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/Modi/Haupt-Konj2.html]  "Der Konjunktiv II wird auch für zögernde, zweifelnde Fragen und Feststellungen/Vermutungen verwendet." Auf der andere seite, "Wenn der Konjunktiv I in einem unabhängigen Satz steht, drückt er einen Wunsch oder eine Aufforderung aus. In dieser Funktion kommt er aber in der Gegenwartssprache nur noch selten vor." (kanoonet)[http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/Modi/Haupt-Konj1.html?MenuId=Word2123150]

Comment: Ah, es ist eine veraltete Konzession http://www.dartmouth.edu/~deutsch/Grammatik/Subjunctive/KonjunktivI.htmes "As in English, the special subjunctive can be used to concede a point, although such constructions are largely obsolete:"  Examples: Sei der Berg auch noch so hoch, wir werden ihn ersteigen. However high the mountain may be, we'll climb it. Er möge schreien, soviel er will, wir kaufen es ihm nicht. He can yell as much as he wants, but we won't buy it for him

Comment: Nein, denn Einstein korrigiert sich hier ja selbst. Er hatte die Quantentheorie ja zunächst abgelehnt. Würde er *wäre* statt *sei* oder *ist* verwenden, würde er die Änderung seiner Ansicht ja erneut in Frage stellen. Er verwendet auch *sei* statt *ist* hier wohl bewusst, um darauf hinzuweisen, dass es sich nicht um seinen eigenen Einfall handelt.

Comment: @user5389726598465 If you use Konjunktiv II for "zweifelnde Feststellungen/Vermutungen", it looks like this: "Vielleicht könnte man auch dies und das annehmen." If you say something like "unter der Annahme, dass die Energie diskontinuierlich verteilt wäre", this heavily implies that it is, in fact, not distributed in a dicontinuous way.

Comment: Es ist gängig, in den Naturwissenschaften und insb. der Mathematik Annahmen in den Konjunktiv I zu stellen, um daraus Schlussfolgerungen abzuleiten ([Online Writing Lab der TU Darmstadt](https://www.owl.tu-darmstadt.de/owl/owl_module_1/modulenachfachbereiche/naturwissenschaftenmathematik/051/0051_4.de.jsp))

Comment: @Raketenolli, das ist technisch gesehen nicht richtig. In Formulierungen wie „**Sei** _f_ eine Funktion ...“ ist **sei** der Imperativ, der wie der Konjunktiv I aussieht. Vgl. https://german.stackexchange.com/a/1764/25241 und https://german.stackexchange.com/a/1759/25241.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Die erste Antwort behauptet (korrekt), dass das eine altmodische Verwendung des Konjunktiv I ist, die als Imperativ verstanden wird. Die zweite Antwort ist falsch und wird von keiner Grammatik des Deutschen, die ich kenne gedeckt. Genauso gut könnte man behaupten, dass in "Kannst du das Fenster zumachen" ein Imperativ verwendet wird, weil man den Satz als Aufforderung versteht.